# How to click a button of one form from another form?

Tags: vb6

Say, i've two forms `form1` and `form2`

`form1` has a button name `command1`

and `form2` has a button named `command1`

Question is, how can i simulate `form1.button1` click when i click `form2.button1`

Answer (score 6):

try something like this in Form2:

`Form1.Command1.Value = True`

Hope it will help :)

Comment: Be careful if you have use the non default instance of a form. e.g. `Set F = new Form1: F.Show` You must use the same F vs. Form1 that you created.

Comment: Also be aware of ensuring the secondary form has not been closed or your reference will be invalid. It's better practice to write a single public sub that your button click would trigger, you could then call this from any form you wanted without referencing other forms or their controls.